# How to add together two column values with an UPDATE statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How would I add together two column values within an UPDATE statement in MYSQL using PHP variables:

Here's my code :

```
$sql="UPDATE orders SET  
order_total='$order_total_new' + '$shipping',
order_total_new='$order_total_new',
order_total_new_reason='$order_total_new_reason', 
cashing_up_total='$cashing_up_total',
shipping='$shipping',
refund_total='$refund_total'

WHERE order_id='$order_id'";
```

I'm trying to find the correct syntax for the following line from the above code :

order_total='$order_total_new' + '$shipping',

So the result of this query would look like:

30.00 + 5.00 = 35.00 (enter 35.00 as the value to UPDATE)

Thanks.

Comment: Without single quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing concatenate operator `.`

```
$sql="UPDATE orders SET  
order_total='".($order_total_new + $shipping)."',
order_total_new='".$order_total_new."',
order_total_new_reason='".$order_total_new_reason."', 
cashing_up_total='".$cashing_up_total."',
shipping='".$shipping."',
refund_total='".$refund_total."'

WHERE order_id='".$order_id."'";
```

Provided $order_total_new & $shipping are numbers when declared.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way:

```
   $sql = 'UPDATE orders SET '
          . 'order_total = ' . $order_total_new + $shipping . ', '
          . 'order_total_new = ' . $order_total_new . ', '
          . 'order_total_new_reason = ' . $order_total_new_reason . ', '
          . 'cashing_up_total = ' . $cashing_up_total . ', '
          . 'shipping = ' . $shipping . ', '
          . 'refund_total = ' . $refund_total . ', '
          . 'WHERE order_id = ' . $order_id;
```

And I'm strongly asking you to use mysqli::real_escape_string function for your application security.